# Struts 2 Select tag inside Struts2 Jquery Grid Column

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, struts2, struts2-jquery

What is the way to use a Struts2 select tag inside a Struts2 Jquery Grid Column? I couldn't find any useful information in the plugin website, they just talk about a custom formatter using a javascript function, which I have been able to use successful for other needs, but I can't do it with the Struts2 select tag since there's no point of creating Struts2 tags dynamically with javascript. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking at the wrong place. Check [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules), you will understand how to use a `select` tag in jquery grid.